# Elastic search hits are N but returned results are much less

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not sure whether there is a default limit set somewhere, but my Elastic search `hit` entry is telling me that there are 135 hits and I am only getting 10 back.

As it always seems to max at 10, there seems to be definitely a default setting somewhere?

```
[hits] => Array
    (
        [total] => 135
        [max_score] => 1
        [hits] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array (  /* document content */ )
                /*  and so on ... */ 
                [9] => Array ( /* document content */ )
            )  
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default`Elastic Search` returns `10` hits. You can change it using `size`

```
GET /index/type/_search?size=100
```